# How to select only the last n days every month in the given pd.DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

For example,

```
datetimeidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(
          ['1999-03-01', '1999-03-02', '1999-03-03', '1999-03-04',
           '1999-03-05', '1999-03-08', '1999-03-09', '1999-03-10',
           '1999-03-11', '1999-03-12', '2021-11-16', '2021-11-17', 
           '2021-11-18', '2021-11-19', '2021-11-22', '2021-11-23', 
           '2021-11-24', '2021-11-26', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-30'])
```

if `n=3`, what I want is:

```
datetimeidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(
          ['1999-03-10','1999-03-11', '1999-03-12', 
           '2021-11-26', '2021-11-29', '2021-11-30'])
```

The point is that I want to select only from the 'given' `pd.DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could group by year and month, then use the [pandas.Series.tail](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tail.html);

```py
n = 3

pd.DatetimeIndex(datetimeidx
                  .to_series()
                  .groupby([datetimeidx.year, datetimeidx.month])
                  .tail(n))

DatetimeIndex(['1999-03-10', '1999-03-11', '1999-03-12', '2021-11-26',
               '2021-11-29', '2021-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
g = pd.Series(datetimeidx.year).astype(str) + '-' + pd.Series(datetimeidx.month).astype(str)
print(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.Series(datetimeidx).sort_values().groupby(g).tail(3)))
```